# Updating a SQLite database over the air

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, windows-phone-8

My app has an SQLite database file which is copied as a content into the solution itself.
All I am currently doing is accessing its tables by using queries. I want to add functionality to update this database file on the users device after the app is installed on it. Is it technically possible to do this on a Windows Phone 8, I do know that this is possible in androids and iPhones.

What kind of web service would i need ? etc etc

More info: I am using SQLite extension for windows phone , sql-net Nuget package.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... What you want do exactly? You are building a windows-phone's app that use a sqlite db. When the user install what you want do?

Comment: the database file is bundled with the app itself , but later on i want  to add the ability to update this database file OTA

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible update a sqlite db directly via OTA because it's an embedded database.
You two options:

- Change database and choose for example [SQLitening](http://www.sqlitening.com/support/index.php) (is a client/server implementation of the popular SQLite database)
- Use the socket in your application and when yuo want change something in the database the server send the sql query, the client receive it and then make the query

Answer (score 0):

There is a never-released extension for SQLite called [OTA](https://sqlite.org/draft/ota.html#:%7E:text=The%20OTA%20extension%20is%20an,power%20navigation%20devices%20via%20wireless.) that does precisely what you want, it seems. Here is its [closed branch](https://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?t=ota-update).